# A quiz question based on subspace topology i am unable to solve

Tags: general-topology

While trying sample quiz papers I am unable to solve this particular question in topology.

It's image:[image]

Questions:
(1) why 4th option is false. I think B can be deformed to a unit circle. So, it must hold.

I am unable to reason why 3rd option must hold or not.

Any help would be really appreciated .

Comment: What is the unit circle?

Comment: @A.G. $x^{2} + y^{2} $ =1 .

Comment: "Can be deformed" is ambiguous. $B$ is homotopy equivalent to a circle, and it includes a circle as a deformation retract, but that's not the same as being homeomorphic. You would probably do well to revisit the definition of "homeomorphic" and try to apply it in the specific case of $B$ and the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C: The image of a connected set is connected.  The image of $A$ intersects some connected component $X_1$ non-trivially. The image of $A$ must be contained in $X_1$, otherwise its union with $X_1$ would be a larger connected set, contradicting the maximality of $X_1$.  Similarly the image of $B$ is contained in some connected component $X_2$.  As the map is surjective $X=X_1 \cup X_2$.

D: If you remove any point from $S^1$ the result is contractible.  If you remove any point from $B$, the result has fundamental group $F_2$ (free on two generators).

D: (without algebraic topology) If you remove any two distinct points from $S^1$ the result is not connected.  If you remove any two distinct points from $B$, the result is connected.

Comment: I haven't studied algebraic topology, So can you please give a reason not based on algebraic topology for D?

Comment: in line 4 of your answer pre image need not be open as connected components of Rational numbers are 1 point sets.

Comment: Have added answer to D without algebraic topology.  You are right about C - I need to fix this.

Comment: I have Fixed C.

Comment: Kindly define $X_{1}$ in part C.

Comment: The space $X$ may be partitioned into connected components (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Connected_components).  Thus as $A$ is not the empty set, its image under the surjective map must have non trivial intersection with at least one of the connected components of $X$.  We call this connected component $X_1$.  We then use the result that if the intersection of two connected sets is non-trivial, there union is connected. By definition of connected component, a connected component is not contained in any strictly larger connected set.  Changed wording to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is false, $B$ is false, $C$ is true, $D$ is false.

If $A$ were true, the set $A$ would be compact, which it is not. Or take $f(x) = \frac{1}{1-\|x\|}$ which is a counterexample.

$B$: the set $B$ (And $A$ too) is connected, so every continuous function to $\Bbb N$ is constant.

$C$: $f[A]$ and $f[B]$ are connected in $X$ and if they don't overlap, we have two components of $X$ (otherwise one).

$D$: The dimensions are wrong for a start. So $B$ and the unit circle are not homeomorphic.